# Show different output based on the ${selectedcount}

Tags: javascript, html

I wants the **Prediction Formula**  to display as:

if ${selectedcount} **> 30**

Display as **${selectedcount} / 3 + 5**

if ${selectedcount} **< 30**

Display as **${selectedcount} / 3 - 5**

P/S: Not the calculation but just the formula

```
<div id="demo" align="center"></div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var selectedcount = '';

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `
<table class="table table-striped table-dark" style="width:600px; float: right; margin-right: 330px;">
     <tr>
         <td style="text-align: center; color: #000000; text-align: left;">Current total number of students:</td>
         <td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; color: #000000; text-align: left;">${selectedcount} students</td>
     </tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center; color: #000000; text-align: left;">Prediction Formula:</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; color: #0000A0; text-align: left;">Number of students > 30 <br> <b>Average = number of students / 3 + 5</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="text-align: center; color: #0000A0; text-align: left;">Number of students < 30 <br> <b>Average = number of students / 3 - 5</b></td>
  </tr>
</table>`

  }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#prg").change( function(){
      selectedcount = $('#prg option:selected').data('prgcount');
      if(selectedcount > 30){
        average = selectedcount / 3 + 5;
      } else{
        average = selectedcount / 3 - 5;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Currently the **Prediction Formula** row doesn't captured the ${selectedcount} from **Current total number of students** as shown below:

**Screencapture**

[image]

I've removed some unrelated codes, I hope it helps. Please assist on the above. Thank you.

**Expected output**

*if ${selectedcount} > 30*
[image]

*if ${selectedcount} < 30*
[image]

Comment: What exactly should the prediction formula show?  I mean which text should replace with what. Also where is `average` used or initiated other than the `if` block.

Comment: Hi @AbhishekKumarTiwari I've just added the expected output as above.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, You want to show something like `Average = 30 / 3 + 5` ? If that is the case shouldn't you replace `number of students` plain text with `${selectedcount}` in your code? Just like you did in the previous row

Comment: But the row should change based on ${selectedcount} either > 30 or < 30. Have you seen my expected output screencapture, the two tables? The data is exactly alike that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the sign and denominator before rendering based on your condition.

Something like this.

```js
function myFunction() {

   var predicDenom = parseInt(selectedcount) > 30 ? '3+5 : '3-5'; //Store the denominator based on number of students
   var predicSign = parseInt(selectedcount) > 30 ? '>' : '<'; // Also store the sign

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `
<table class="table table-striped table-dark" style="width:600px; float: right; margin-right: 330px;">
     <tr>
         <td style="text-align: center; color: #000000; text-align: left;">Current total number of students:</td>
         <td style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; color: #000000; text-align: left;">${selectedcount} students</td>
     </tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center; color: #000000; text-align: left;">Prediction Formula:</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; color: #0000A0; text-align: left;">Number of students ${predicSign} 30 <br> <b>Average = number of students / ${predicDenom}</b></td>
  </tr>
</table>`

  }
```

Comment: Hi @AbhishekKumarTiwari - I tried on this code but it doesn't works. The output is Number of students {$predicSign} 30
Average = number of students / {$predicDenom}

Comment: Made a typo in the variables name, have made changes. Can you try again.

Comment: Had mistakenly put the $ inside the braces. Now it should work